# Cannot load bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried doing carousel in bootstrap but it does not load on Firefox or Google chrome in Windows 8.This is the code I wrote,so can someone please explain to me what i did wrong.

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/Capture.PNG" />
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/img1.PNG" />
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/img3.PNG" />
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control"  href="#mycarousel"  data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control"  href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's your closing div tags on your `<div class="item">` elements?

Answer (score 3):

You should include carousel.js in bootstrap3 and close your **div** `item`

Comment: Just quick question, I've got a carousel working without carousel.js in bs3 and it works fine. What's the advantages to including carousel.js?

Comment: @BeatAlex You likely have the relevant Javascript saved in a different JS file - Bootstrap packages many different JS bits together by default. Carousel.js is much more specialized, it only contains the JS necessary for the carousel to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please include carousel.js in your html document

Refer to download carousel.js:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

Close your div "item" tag, then set the first "item" to "active"

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="Capture.PNG" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img1.PNG" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img3.PNG" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then the most important thing, is **don't forget to load "bootstrap.css"**
=> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css.
Because bootsrap used that css file.